# Count how many times a word is used. C

Tags: c, parsing

I am trying to count the number of loops and emptylines in a string entered by a user. So here is the way I did it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, lines, loopF = 0, loopW = 0, loopDW = 0, empty = 0;
    char *p, str[200];
    const char test[10] = "while";
    char *f;
    printf("Enter a string. Ctrl+Z for exit.\n");
    while (fgets(str, 200, stdin) != NULL) {
        if (f = strstr(str, test)) { //first way
            loopW++;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
            // count loops
            if (str[i] == 'f' && str[i + 1] == 'o' && str[i + 2] == 'r') {
                loopF++;
            }
            if (str[i] == 'w' && str[i + 1] == 'h' && str[i + 2] == 'i'
                    && str[i + 3] == 'l' && str[i + 4] == 'e') { // second way
                loopW++;
            }
            if (str[i] == 'd' && str[i + 1] == 'o') {
                loopDW++;
                if (loopDW >= 1)
                    loopW--;
            }
        }
        // count empty lines
        p = str;
        lines = 0;
        while (*p != '\n') {
            if (*p != ' ') {
                lines = 1;
            }
            p++;
        }
        if (!lines) {
            empty++;
            lines = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("---------------------\n");
    printf(" Empty lines: %d \n\n", empty);
    printf(" Number of loops:\n");
    printf(" For: %d \n", loopF);
    printf(" While: %d \n", loopW);
    printf(" Do/While: %d \n", loopDW);
    printf("---------------------\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I did it for 2 ways only for "while" to test but when a user types "whilethis" or "thiswhile" it counts it(which is not what I want). I want when there is only a while(a loop) to be counted and not with other symbols but i have no idea how to do it. Same is for do/while and for loops. Any help here? :)

Comment: `<ctype.h>` has functions that classify characters. If you want to find whole words, test whether the characters just before and after the word are not letters with `isalnum`. Make sure that you don't access the character left of the beginning of the line.

Comment: it must be sth like this `while (` or `while(` , after each while loop we have space or (  , otherwise it is not a loop , it's something like variable name ...

Comment: just be aware of do while , it has `{` after  do , you must check space and {

Comment: If you are going to write a parser, you need to be very clear bout your grammar (e.g. what are your "spaces" and other separators? do you have comments? etc.). Also you have the major problem of line continuity with your buffer (if a line is over 200 characters fgets will split into multiple parts and that will need to be addressed). Altogether, even for something as simple as this there are lots of pitfalls and reinventing the solution will be tedious and buggy. It would be way simpler to simply define your grammar and use [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/)

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution also needs to handle strings and comments

```
print("I have no for() loops")
/* commented out for() loop */
char* c = "for()\"loop\\";
```

If you do not care about this, and really want to use plain C, I would recommend "strtok" function which splits string into the words using delimiters (which would be basically all non-alphanumeric symbols in your case -- space, brackets, comma, etc...). Then once you have words, you can just strcmp() them with "do", "while" or "for"